# identifying common *non-continuous* subsequences representing occurrences

Tags: r, subsequence

Consider the following dataset:

```
set.seed(50)
d = matrix(rbinom(1000, 1, 0.9), ncol = 20)
```

Each row corresponds to an object, and each column corresponds to a 
measurement of the object. For example, rows could be individuals in a 
study and columns could be repeated measures through time. In this 
case, measurements are TRUE/FALSE indicating presence or absence of an 
object.

**I am looking for an algorithm that will allow me to identify the 
maximal collection of rows  that have `n` coincident observations**. 
In other words, I'm looking for a way to filter for the rows that all 
have `n` TRUE values in the same columns. A member of the group can 
have more than `n` TRUE values though.

The trivial example: the rows with 20 (all) TRUE values are captured by

```
which(apply(d, 1, all))
```

which identifies rows `3, 10, 12, 24, 36, 39, 48, 50`. Similarly, it's
easy to identify all the unique sequences and identify groups that share
the same observations:

```
unique.series = d[which(!duplicated(d)),]
groups = vector("list", nrow(unique.series))
for(i in seq_along(groups))
  groups[[i]] = which(apply(d, 1, function(x) 
    identical(x, unique.series[i,])))
```

But what if I want all groups with 19 or more observations? For example,
groups `3` (rows `3, 10, 12, 24, 36, 39, 48, 50`) and `21` 
(rows `23, 32, 40`) only differ by observation `9` 
(group 3 has an observation, but group `21` does not). How can I 
programmatically identify series that partially match, i.e. contain some
subset of matching observations? This seems like a subsequence matching 
problem, but it's a bit more abstract because the subsequences don't need to be continuous.

One way might be to use regular expressions, but I can't get it to work
right:

```
unique.strings = lapply(
apply(unique.series, 1, function(x) 
    which(as.logical(x))),
  paste,
  collapse = ","
)
reg.strings = paste0("^", lapply(
  apply(unique.series, 1, function(x) 
    sprintf("(%d)", which(as.logical(x)))), 
  paste, collapse = "+(,[0-9],)*"), "$")  
lapply(unique.strings, grep, x =  unique.strings) # NOT CORRECT
```

I would appreciate any alternative algorithms, regex-based or other.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but I did get more than halfway there. I abandoned the regex approach and instead
adopted a binary matrix approach.

A collection of coincident observations will be represented in the occurrence
matrix as a block of TRUE values. I don't require that 
observations be consecutive, i.e. the row/column ordering of the 
matrix doesn't matter. Therefore, I can simply rearrange my matrix so 
that occurrences are grouped in blocks, and then use block detection
or clustering algorithms to extract set of observations. There are two 
components to this procedure: first, rearrange the matrix to make it as 
"blocky" as possible by column/row swapping. Second, identify the 
blocks in the arranged matrix.

The arrangement part is actually really easy. I used the `seriation` 
package to rearrange the matrix into blocks.

```
set.seed(50)
d = matrix(as.logical(rbinom(50, 1, 0.75)), ncol = 10)
rownames(d) = LETTERS[1:5]   # individual IDs
colnames(d) = month.abb[1:10]

library(seriation)
o = seriate(d)
d.a = permute(d, o)            # rearranged matrix
```

I haven't decided on a good approach for the block detection, but there are several SO questions that deal with largest block detection (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610071/naive-way-to-find-largest-block-in-a-rectangle-of-1s-and-0s), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726632/dynamic-programming-largest-square-block)). I am hoping I can adapt these algorithms to find the largest block of width *n* or something like that. I will update this answer if I find a good solution.